# view model function is not a function error in knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have this view model,

```
define(['text!./form.html', 'knockout', '../../home', '../../users'],  
  function(template, ko,homeModel,userModel) {

    function  registerUserViewModel() {
        var self = this;
        ...
        self.registerUser = function(){
            ...
            $.ajax({
                url: 'server/registerUser.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: {"data":credentials},
                success: function (result) {
                    if(result == "Successful"){
                        homeModel.viewModel.addUser("Jun","5:30");
                    }else{
                        alert(result);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        return self;
    }
    return {
        viewModel: registerUserViewModel,
        template: template
    };
});
```

Here is my homeViewModel,

```
define(["knockout", "text!./home.html", "../../users"],  
  function (ko, homeTemplate, userModel) {
    function homeViewModel(params) {
        var self = this;
        ...
        self.users = ko.observableArray([]);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'server/getUsers.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {"data":id},
            success: function (result) {
                var row = JSON.parse(result)
                for(var i=0;i<row.length;i++){
                    self.users.push(new userModel.userModel(row[i]["name"],row[i]["time"],row[i]["id"]));
                }
            }
        });
        self.addUser = function(name,time){
            self.users.push(new userModel.userModel(name,time));
        }
        return self;
    }
    return { viewModel: homeViewModel, template: homeTemplate };
});
```

When I go to the page,
There is an error,

> homeModel.viewModel.addUser is not a function.

but I assigned a function to `self.addUser`. I tried `homeModel.addUser` but still not working.

Is there any other way to simply add a new userModel to self.users array?

Comment: have you checked `homeModel` variable's data ?

Comment: alert(homeModel) = object, alert(homeModel.vieModel) = to homeViewModel code above

Comment: alert(home|Model.viewModel.addUser) = undefined

Comment: How/where is the `homeViewModel` instantiated? Aren't you referencing the constructor rather than an instance?

Comment: I guess the "homeModel" (the instance) should be passed to the "registerUserViewModel" component via params. Possibly through markup.

Comment: For faster solution can you please setup a sample in jsfiddle explaining your problem...

Comment: We need to see the markup with the bindings in order to better answer this question.